# I'm not a fan of hedgehogs

Tags: riddle, rhyme, science

> Many have tried to beat me, many have failed.
> The earliest to succeed, is long-tailed.
>
> If you break me, silence is all you'll hear.
> The thunder will make the others fear.
>
> Others will tremble at your might,
> As you break me in their sight.
>
> The flash of a whip kills me as it sings,
> As well as the man who rode a bull with wings.

What am I?

Comment: I don't know how I feel about this puzzle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> The sound barrier

I'm not a fan of hedgehogs

> Sonic the Hedgehog

Many have tried to beat me, many have failed.
The earliest to succeed, is long-tailed.

> It is thought that long-tailed dinosaurs could crack their tails like a whip

If you break me, silence is all you'll hear.
The thunder will make the others fear.

> If you break the sound barrier, there is a sonic boom audible to others... but not audible to the pilot, who by definition is traveling faster than the sound can catch up with her.

Others will tremble at your might,
As you break me in their sight.

> I think most people would tremble if confronting a sonic boom

The flash of a whip kills me as it sings,
As well as the man who rode a bull with wings.

> Whips crack faster than the speed of sound. The 'bull with wings' is Felix Baumgartner, who performed a freefall from space, breaking the sound barrier as he did so. He was sponsored by Red Bull.

Comment: The bull with wings probably means rot(Erq-ohyy raretl qevax) and thus rot13(Sryvk Onhztnegare'f fhcre-fbavp fxlqvir)    EDIT:  aaaand you already got there.  Nice!